# Divine And Healing

Tags: riddle, word

> ___   ___    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___
>
> Love contained in  232 parts
> Would apparently seem amazing
> If the world turns upside down

Answer contains 3 letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a possible solution working backwards...

Divine and Healing
_ _ _ _ _ _ _

> My proposal is to find something that is 'divine and healing' which fits into the seven blanks.

Love contained in 232 parts

> Since we are looking for a 3 letter word, we would like blanks 2,3,2 to spell that final word, which should be associated strongly with 'love'. Since today is Mother's Day (in many places), let's assume the word is MOM, giving us:  _ M O _ _ _ _.

Would apparently seem amazing
If the world turns upside down

> This suggests to me that we must actually turn the word upside-down *before* we extract our target word MOM. So MO becomes OW, and 2,3,2 becomes 6,5,6 (temporarily for now).
>  So we now have: _ _ _ _ O W _

> Going back to our 'divine and healing' clue, "Saint" or "Saints" would be a perfect fit based on the definition. In fact, "Hallow" or "Hallows" is an archaic noun that is a synonym for saint/saints. They are definitely 'divine and healing'. So we can use the noun 'hallows', defined as 'saints or holy people' to fill in the blanks:
>  H A L L O W S
>  Turn it upside down: S M O 7 7 V H (roughly)
>  Find the letters at indexes 2,3,2 (232 parts): M O M
>  Our answer is "**MOM**", someone who indeed embodies love!

Comment: Nice! Great Thinking about the HALLOWS and Turn Upside Down :) Yet the transformation regarding "turns upside down" seems to be somewhat unfitting since an extra reflection is used. There's a hidden hint in the title you can try upon

Comment: I'm marking your answer correct, although it doesn't follow the hints in the "proper" direction, the final answer is correct, and no one else has provided any other solution.

Comment: @thisIs4d It's fine if you want to leave it open if a better explanation exists. We'll eventually find it - though I am stumped so far.